# Cant get the progress multiple times, just once. laravel-ffmpeg

Tags: php, laravel, ffmpeg

I am encountering some problems getting the progress percentage for package called - [laravel-ffmpeg](https://github.com/protonemedia/laravel-ffmpeg). It is called just once when the file has finished transcoding. I tried small and big file, got the same result. Here is the code.

```
FFMpeg::open('test_video.mp4')
    ->export()
    ->onProgress(function ($percentage, $remaining) {
        echo "{$remaining}";
        Asset::where('parent_catalog', '7a42ae6d-872d-4c2c-8e85-832ed9902fac')->update(['proxy_status' => $percentage]);
    })->save("test_output.mp4");
```

Could it be package issue or my lack of knowledge with PHP?

Comment: Your webserver is likely waiting for the response to finish before sending it. You should consider making the ffmpeg job a queued job, and using Laravel's broadcasting tools in the onProgress callback to something like Laravel Echo.

Comment: Ahh. How complicated. What if I would like to save the percentage in db? Idea how I wanted to run it is with artisan command, so its already in background process.

Comment: Yes, if you ran it in an Artisan command in the background, updating a database field would work; you'd need to have some sort of polling (refreshing or AJAX calls) on the web side of things. Don't shy away from broadcasting, though; Echo via Pusher is pretty easy to set up.

Comment: You are saying that seperate solution would be polling with ajax? If so, then what does it gives me, if I cant get the file transcoding progress in db(except 100%)?

Comment: I guess I did not wrote the issue good enough. The onProgress(...) is just running once when its done(100%), but while the process is in its 20%, 50%, 70% I would like to update db with this data.